# JPQL: How can I use the row as a parameter for a stored function call?

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a stored function called `validate_row` that takes a row from a table and returns a boolean, and I want to perform a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM table T WHERE validate_row(T) = true
```

Executing this query in PostgreSQL directly works, but the following JPQL annotation will use the table's primary key as a function parameter instead of the row:

```
@Query("SELECT someDAO from table T WHERE function('validate_row', T) = true")
```

Any ideas of how to make it use the row as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

By default, @Query run query as JPQL. So to run query as SQL native, use `nativeQuery = true`.

Try this :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM table t WHERE validate_row(t) = true", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: I am not trying to run the query natively.